# the usages of should

Tags: should

In a TOEFL conversation, the professor said: "If you're a copper miner, you won't lose any sleep should the penny get – if you'll excuse the expression – pinched out of existence."

I am confused by the use of "should" here, as a proper way I would think of is to put "should" after penny – 
you won't lose any sleep the penny should get – so why is it the case?

By the way, what does the professor mean why he said "the penny get pinched out of existence”?

Comment: The phrase "should the penny get..." means "if the penny is..." and for the second question, the professor is making a play on the phrase [**penny-pinching**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/penny-pinching).

Comment: *You won't lose any sleep [] the penny [should] get pinched out of existence* is ungrammatical. The original location of *should* is normal. But if you want to explain *why* you think it belongs in the other location, there might be some way of addressing that thought—or rephrasing things where the new location could be grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

This use of "should the penny get" means essentially "if the penny got".  ("Should XXX get" is a bit of an idiom, and there's no direct replacement for "should" that I can think of.)

"Penny pinching" is another idiom, referring to stinginess.

Comment: Though that's not the way it's being used here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Which "it"?  Obviously, "penny pinching" is being used as a pun of sorts.